# Session Timeout in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working in a web application project using asp.net ,my problem is I want to increase my Session time out to 1 hour ,For that I have used in web.config file:

```
 <sessionState timeout="60" cookieless="false" mode="InProc"/>
```

but it is not working.

The Particular Page automatically redirects to login page after a few minutes.Why it is happening so?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the timeout to 1 hour then use the following

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
     <sessionState timeout="60"></sessionState>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that client cookie is being expired and the IIS redirects user to login page to authenticate again. It is not relevant with `sessionState` timeout. Try to set timeout of `FormsAuthentication`;

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogIn" timeout="60" />
</authentication>
```

Comment: i tried using that....i am getting the error as "The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid"

Comment: What is your authentication type ? Isn't it FormsAuthentication ?

Comment: <authentication mode="Windows"/>

Comment: I couldn't understand that if it has Windows Authentication, how the client is being redirected to login page ? Is there a login page ?

Answer (score 1):

In web config file, change sessionstate timeout propety

```
<system.web>  
    <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="60"/>
</system.web>
```